# splash with a music play?

Tags: android, splash-screen

detail code as below,i want to implement a 10 second music playing ,after the music stop automatic stop,then to another activity,current issue is when the home key is pressed during the splash screen going on,an error occur and the another activity can still enter in(it's not reasonable...) anyone can give me some help?

public class ActivitySplash extends Activity {
    private static MediaPlayer playSong;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    fontsCustom();

    playSong = MediaPlayer.create(ActivitySplash.this,
            R.raw.fsir200splashmusic);
    playSong.start();

    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (playSong.isPlaying()) {
                    sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent beginActivityInt = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.ACTIVITYMAIN");
                startActivity(beginActivityInt);
            }

        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

        return true; // always eat it!
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
        return true;
    else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void fontsCustom() {
    FontCustom fonts = new FontCustom(ActivitySplash.this);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_layout_splash);
    fonts.setupLayoutTypefaces(layout);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    playSong.release();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: forgot:music playing time is no limit,if the music is 20 secs,then the activity switch should be 20 secs,no a fixed time given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to set
    `playsong.OnCompletionListener(ActivitySplash.this)` and 
implement your logic in

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) 
{
  // Write your code
}
```

Please refer to the below code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static MediaPlayer playsong;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    playsong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pp);
    playsong.start();
    playsong.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    playsong.release();
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
 Thread t;
 MediaPlayer mpl;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     final SplashActivity ss=this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    mpl=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog1);
    mpl.start();
    mpl=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cat3);
    mpl.start();

  Thread t=new Thread(){
      public void run() {
          try{
              sleep(10000);
          }
          catch(Exception e){

          }
          mpl.stop();
          Intent i=new Intent(ss,MainActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
      }
  };
   t.start();

}
}
```